# I need to find a manga about two brothers, one of whom is skilled with magic

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manga(?) is about two brothers. One is short and the other is tall. The short one is pretty skilled with magic and the other is pure force

They try to hide that they are strong and they are kinda broke. I remember that the short one went to an arena to fight. He is is always wearing a mask so nobody knows him

There was a scene where his brother got mad and couldn't hold his power but his brother managed to calm him down.

Comment: This question appears to be about a fantasy work (it features someone who is "skilled with magic", and I assume this doesn't mean sleight-of-hand), so I have migrated it here, pursuant to https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11552/.

Comment: My first thought would be *Full Metal Alchemist*, but there the taller one would appear to be wearing a mask (actually, he's basically a living suit of armor; he's also the younger brother).

Comment: [Mob Psycho 100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mob_Psycho_100) seems to have similar elements as well, but missing a few key points.

Answer (score 2):

[*Our Blood Oath*](https://www.viz.com/our-blood-oath)?

There are 2 brothers, one is a vampire that can make magic weapons out of blood and is fairly short.

> Shin the orphan was taken in by a vampire couple who later gave birth to a younger brother for him. Life was good for a time, but when a long-haired vampire kills their parents, the younger brother, Ko, is in peril. Desperate, Shin and Ko make a Blood Oath of Darkness. But what does this mean for them?!
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

I happened to run across your question when I was looking for what I believe is the exact same series.  The series you are looking for is The Great Conqueror.  Here are the links to [The Great Conqueror Manhwa](http://fanfox.net/manga/the_great_conqueror/) and if you would prefer the novel it was based on, [The Great Conqueror novel](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/the-great-conqueror/)

> Summary:
>   This manga is set in a world where beastmen are at the top of reign over the world. In this story two beast brothers from the bear clan got admitted into an exclusive combat academy for the noble beastmen. There, they are treated as nothing more than trash. However, it turns out that each of them have unique abilities that are sought after by many others. Join them on their journey to get a better life as well as proof to all those snobby noble beastmen amd ladies who look down on them.

The series actually seems similar to [Star Martial God Technique](https://mangazuki.me/manga/star-martial-god-technique/)
It's also about the 2 brothers.

Comment: This answer would be improved by adding excerpts from your links so people can judge the answer without having to rely on external links.

Comment: And exactly what excerpts would improve this?

Comment: Anything that indicates *why* this is the correct answer. A reference to the brothers' height or magic/fighting abilities or lack of money. Summaries are fine if there aren't good passages to quote.

Comment: This is essentially a Chinese comic book.  The summary for it is unhelpful in regards to the questions the OP asked and as for references, was I supposed to insert images of each chapter into my response as proof?